# Azure Cosmos REST API query Last n Records

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing a blazor wasm app using REST API to access a cosmos db database, using the cosmos db emulator for testing. I have code written for reading records, posting data and sending a SQL query.

What I am struggling to find out using the REST api, how is is possible to read the last n records, and then after that read n-skip 100 records reading backwards ?

I could use x-ms-continuation header for paging records but that appears to be only available for reading data forwards.

It will be quite a few records as it is a time series db.
I am looking to the REST api version of OFFSET LIMIT based on the items timestamp. Once an item is there it is never updated.

Comment: Do you know the total number of records?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "*last n records*" - are you referring to the last n documents inserted or modified within a collection or partition, based on timestamp (`_ts`)? Is it the last n documents within a query's results? Are you looking for behavior similar to Cosmos DB's `OFFSET` / `LIMIT` clause? Please edit to clarify.

Comment: Per your edit: Have you tried executing a query (including `OFFSET` and `LIMIT`) via the [Query Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/cosmos-db/query-documents) REST API call? Maybe this will take care of what you're trying to achieve...

Comment: Maybe just use the JS SDK in the browser, alongside your Blazor code? JS SDK is designed to be run in the browser. Handling all the error cases for query is a months long endeavor. It is complex and you should start by reverse engineering an SDK. First step would be to get the query plan for your query, then execute the query plan. The query plan will tell you how many pages to skip, though you should try to use continuation tokens if you can for efficiency.

Comment: I don't know that the cosmos db will be such a good fit for our application. We will be storing quite a bit of data for each client on a per minute basis and using OFFSET LIMIT (or its equivalent) to do the query and although that appears to have been added to api support recently, according to what this man has written the cost in RU's may get quite high. https://mikaberglund.com/2020/03/26/why-i-love-cosmos-db/

Answer (score 0):

You could try using

```
select top <n> <field_name>
```

to get n items. And to make it last n items you could try

```
order by <collection_id>._ts desc
```

in your query where `_ts` is the timestamp when the item was stored.